How can I reduce the size of a PDF file in Java using PDFBox or other libraries?
I'm working on a Java project where I need to reduce the file size of a PDF. I’m using PDFBox /itextPdf to handle PDF files, but I’m not sure how to optimize or compress the PDF to reduce its size.
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
// Use a ByteArrayOutputStream for the compressed PDF output
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  // Use the PdfStamper for incremental saving
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
  // Set full compression
  stamper.setFullCompression();
  // Close the stamper to finalize the PDF
  stamper.close();
} finally {
  // Always close the reader in a finally block to avoid resource leaks
  reader.close();
}
// Return the compressed PDF as a byte array
return outputStream.toByteArray();


Have you tried googling for a PDF compression tool and evaluating the options?  Or googling for StackOverflow questions on "pdf compression java".

There is not the one command to compress PDFs. There are many possible inefficiencies in PDFs so a tool would have to watch for each of these possible inefficiencies. Likely a project for a few months. What we could help is if you have one PDFs of a series coming from the same source, we could have a look on how to improve the size.

Indeed, you can use PDFBox, iText, and other general purpose PDF libraries to build a tool to compress PDFs but they don't contain finished such tools yet. For this you have to decide what kind of losses you allow during compression. And you always have to be aware that your input documents may already have been compressed by some such tool and you cannot compress them further without allowing for more losses.

This question is similar to: PDF Compression Techniques. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
